# Spitting file into multiple files

Tags: regex, bash

I've got a large file in the following format:

```
From fc2868d745defcc4deb0ebdce8fe8dac78b447ea Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: email address
message content

From 39a833c2f01030619629daa3b613e3985b2e4e7a Mon Sep 17 00:00:01 2001    
From: email address
message content

From 833c2f01030619629daa3b613e3985b2e4e7a427 Mon Sep 17 00:00:01 2001
From: email address
message content
```

I'd like to split the file into multiple files, so the first file contains

```
    From fc2868d745defcc4deb0ebdce8fe8dac78b447ea Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
    From: email address
    message content
```

Next file contains next section.

The key that determines the next file is "From [a-z][0-9]"

So "From space some letter/number"

Message content is multiple lines, up to 1000

Any ideas how to do this in bash?

Example containing 3 messages: http://pastebin.com/xWmuzfRC

Comment: Can message appear in multiple lines or just one line?

Comment: I've updated question. Message will be over multiple lines. Anything from 10 to 1000.

Comment: Is there a blank line before every `From ...` line as shown?

Comment: Yes. There will be  a blank line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '/^From [[:alnum:]]+/{if (fn) close (fn); fn = "file" ++i ".txt"}
          {print > fn} END{close(fn)}' file
```

This will create output files as `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`.

Comment: The message content will have blank lines in it, so you only want to increment the filename for `From ` records, but print every record to the "current" filename.

Answer (score 2):

```
#script 20151110f.sh  
#input file: 20151110f.dat  
#usage bash 20151110f.sh 20151110f.dat  

inf=$1 # source file  
num=1
while read -r line  
do
    echo "$line" | grep -q "From [a-z0-9]" # check if a new message  
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        file="file"${num}.dat
        echo "$line" > $file
        num=$((num + 1))  #inc so that next file name will be one higher  
    else
        echo "$line" >> $file
    fi
done < "$inf"
```

Comment: You can remove the use of grep: `if [[ $line == "From "[a-z0-9]* ]]; then`

Comment: Also, to maintain leading/trailing whitespace, use `while IFS= read -r line`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this regexp.

```
(From\s.*\n+From:\s+.*\n+.*\n)
```

See this example:
https://regex101.com/r/fJ2rF9/1

Comment: doesnt seem to work if message content is multiple lines.

Comment: you can paste all the data in pastebin? (delete all the private data) - but is important to get the structure o of the data.

Comment: I've added the pastebin to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will work:

```
(^From.*\n)(From:.*\n)((?!From)[\s\S])*$
```

- Group 1: Match everything that beggins with `From`, to the end of the current line.
- Group 2: Match everything that beggins with `From:`, to the end of the current line.
- Group 3: Match everything, including line breaks, except  `From`.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaghh...Turns out the large file is from git and can be split with `git mailsplit` :)

git mailsplit
Splits a mbox file or a Maildir into a list of files: "0001" "0002" .. in the specified directory so you can process them further from there.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mailsplit

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10161037)

Comment: @aschipfl No, this **is** an answer.

Comment: @KevinGuan, for an answer to this question, I was expecting a bit more than just "take this tool"...

Comment: @aschipfl That's a good idea. So to OP: While this tool may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your tool suggestion.